# How do I initialize a custom ViewController when there's no Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

I do not have storyboard enabled.  I am initializing the viewcontroller like so:

```
var customViewController = CustomViewController();
```

then doing this says `customViewController` is nil:

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(customViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Do you call the tow lines of code together? Because, using `CustomViewController()` is ok to initialize a ViewController

Comment: create a nib file and use method initWithNibName:bundle:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried and succeeded

```
import Foundation
class MyCustomViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

and push

```
var customViewController = MyCustomViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(customViewController, animated: true)
```

have anything in your CustomViewController ?